# JsonArray parsing

Tags: android, json, getjson

I'm parsing a json file but i get this message: **org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of** 
    the contetnn of the file is:

Comment: post relative  json parsing code then we will to help u more

Comment: `End of input at character 0 of` Of what?  You're missing the part of the error that'll tell us where the problem is.  I'm expecting it to say something like "of line ____".

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure there is not an empty line at the end of the file? Like this:

```
[
{
code: "UNLC",
cours_jour: "40 020",
variation: "0.00"
},
{
code: "UNXC",
cours_jour: "7 450",
variation: "0.00"
}
]
<-- Empty line here!
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON Object fields need to be encapsulated by quotes

IE

```
{
"code": "BOAC",
"cours_jour": "29 000",
"variation": "-1.69"
}
```

How was the JSON file generated?

--Edit

You can use the below code to download the page to a string and then convert it to a JSONArray and then pull each JSONObject. You cannot run any web requests on the main thread so either extend a new asynctask or thread or runnable to perform the below

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("http://www.impaxis-securities.com/securities/cours-actions/cours.json");
        httpost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String response;
        try {
                response = httpclient.execute(httpost, responseHandler);
                JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response);
                int arrLength = arr.length();
                    if(arrLength > 0)
                    {
                        for(int i = 0; i < arrLength; i++)
                        {
                            JSONObject item = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                            String code = item.getString("code");
                            String cours_jour = item.getString("cours_jour");
                            String variation = item.getString("variation");
                            //Either insert to a DB or add to an array list and return it
                        }
                    }
                } 
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            //Issue with web server 
            } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            //Issue with request
            } 
        catch (JSONException e) {
            //ISSUE Parsing JSON from site
        }
```

---Edit

I tested the code and it looks like there is a bug with the JSON plugin/REST service

http://drupal.org/node/1433436

Comment: the json file was generated  by a drupal module.. i don't really know the name of the module but i work with the  json file they give to me..

Comment: Sounds like the array object created by the module isn't putting quotes around it's keys..IE

$a = array("code" => "$code", "cours_jour" => "$cours_jour", "variation" => "$variation");
<br />
json_encode($a);

but instead they're doing 

$a = array(code => "$code", cours_jour => "$cours_jour", variation => "$variation");

Comment: hi. Do you really get the code, cours_jours and variation.?? i do System.out.println(response) int the try catch but i have nothing

Comment: Did you read about the bug in the link http://drupal.org/node/1433436  -- try switching the mode as described in the link and then try my code